# What is the optimal layering strategy of top layer and bottom layer for low-density board design?

Tags: power, emc, pcb-layers, ground-plane, polygon

I'm designing a board tasked with reading power meter information via SPI and displaying it on-screen. I aim to adhere to the layering principles advocated by Fedol Academy, which involve four layers.

[image: Screenshot from YouTube video showing possible PCB stack-ups]

<sub>Image source: [YouTube - Robert Feranec "How to Decide on Your PCB Layer Ordering, Pouring and Stackup (with Rick Hartley)"](https://youtu.be/52fxuRGifLU?t=2890)</sub>

I'm grappling with a key decision regarding the allocation of the top layer. Should I allocate the entire top layer to polygon power, or would it be preferable to ground it and assign only the power components to polygon?

[image: Screenshot of PCB layout]

Additionally, I'm seeking guidance on which stack layer would be optimal for achieving a low-density design. My ultimate objective is to ensure that this board complies with EMC standards.

Comment: My purpose in asking this question is to know whether, according to the reference there is no case that the top layer or the bottom layer is generally considered as a power plan and is completely covered with a power polygon plan. Is this the meaning of this reference to this layer assignment design?

Comment: According to my studies, it seems that in the standard porcelain layer, due to the larger space between the 3rd and 4th layers, it is better to avoid placing VCC and Grand in these two layers Because it is better VCC plan and GND plan layers to be close to each other.